# What to #include for code about windows,raw mouse data

Tags: windows, include

I find the following post very useful to do a project of my own. Here's the newbie question then: what must I include for this to work?

**Link**:
[How to accurately measure mouse movement in inches or centimetres for a mouse with a known DPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455888/how-to-accurately-measure-mouse-movement-in-inches-or-centimetres-for-a-mouse-wi)

**Content**:

> The following code registers the RAWINPUTDEVICE so it can be used in WM_INPUT.

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];
Rid[0].usUsagePage = HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC;
Rid[0].usUsage = HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE; 
Rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;   
Rid[0].hwndTarget = hWnd;
RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0]);
```

The following code acutally uses the Rid variable two determine how many pixels the mouse has moved since the last time WM_INPUT was initiated.

```
case WM_INPUT: 
{
    UINT dwSize = 40;
    static BYTE lpb[40];

    GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, 
                    lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

    if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE) 
    {
        int xPosRelative = raw->data.mouse.lLastX; // Could be 1, or could be more than 1
        int yPosRelative = raw->data.mouse.lLastY; // Could be 1, or could be more than 1!
    } 
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I just found it.
`#include "hidusage.h"`

here's some definitions it has

```
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_POINTER ((USAGE) 0x01)
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE ((USAGE) 0x02)
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_JOYSTICK ((USAGE) 0x04)
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_GAMEPAD ((USAGE) 0x05)
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_KEYBOARD ((USAGE) 0x06)
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_KEYPAD ((USAGE) 0x07)
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_SYSTEM_CTL ((USAGE) 0x80)

typedef USHORT USAGE,*PUSAGE;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include windows.h

...also the HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC and HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE must be defined.

See MSDN..

```
#ifndef HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC
#define HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC         ((USHORT) 0x01)
#endif
#ifndef HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE        ((USHORT) 0x02)
#endif
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ee418864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx