# Trouble catching WM_INPUT message for lParam, to collect Raw Mouse Input

Tags: windows, winapi, c++-cli, raw-input

For my college project I am developing a solution to distinguish between mouse user data from a person with Parkinson's compared to a healthy person. For which I need mouse data, ideally raw.

I presume I have misunderstood how to collect raw mouse input from the WM_INPUT message but I cannot figure it out.

I have been looking at the following thread: [How to accurately measure mouse movement in inches or centimetres for a mouse with a known DPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455888/how-to-accurately-measure-mouse-movement-in-inches-or-centimetres-for-a-mouse-wi)
and Mouse input libraries on github all of which seem to easily catch a WM_INPUT message whose lParam is a handle to some RawInputData with something like this:

```
GetMessage(&msg, GetActiveWindow(), WM_INPUT, 0);
if (msg.message == WM_INPUT){  .....
```

And then retreiving the lParam from the message and collecting the data associated with that handle with:

```
GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
```

However when I call `GetMessage` in my main loop, the function never exits!
Consequently there is no way (that i know of) for me to get a handle to the RawInputData. Especially since the MSDN page just assumes you have the lParam already.

In summary I need a method of getting an lParam to pass to the `GetRawInputData` function which will remain active whether the program is running in the active window of not.

I'm running this code in a blank C++ CLR project in Visual Studio with the "winuser.h" library.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "winuser.h"

#ifndef HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC
#define HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC         ((USHORT) 0x01)
#endif
#ifndef HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE
#define HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE        ((USHORT) 0x02)
#endif

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];
    Rid[0].usUsagePage = HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC;
    Rid[0].usUsage = HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE;
    Rid[0].dwFlags = 0; //ideally RIDEV_INPUTSINK but that prevents registration
    Rid[0].hwndTarget = GetActiveWindow(); //ideally this would be Null to be independent of the active window

    if (RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE) {
        //registration failed. Call GetLastError for the cause of the error
        Console::WriteLine("Registration Error");
    }
    MSG msg;

    while (true) {
        while (GetMessage(&msg, GetActiveWindow(), WM_INPUT, 0) != 0) { //this command is never completed
            DispatchMessage(&msg); //this line is never ran
        }
        if (msg.message == WM_INPUT) {
            Console::WriteLine("caught a message!!!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for `WM_INPUT` states: "Raw input is available only when the application calls `RegisterRawInputDevices` with valid device specifications". Does your application so call?

Comment: The issue could be anywhere, we need to see a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code, I have edited my original post, thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: [Psychic debugging: Why messages aren’t getting processed by your message pump](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140117-00/?p=2053).

Comment: Ok forgive me if I am wrong but what I have taken from that article is, that I should remove the hwnd filter from the `GetMessage` function by passing `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)` instead, however this results in the same behaviour as before with `GetMessage` never returning a value. Interestingly `peekMessage` does return and sets values within the `msg` object. However I doubt this is exactly efficient code:  `while (true) {
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    if (msg.message == WM_INPUT) {
     Console::WriteLine("Found a WMM_INPUT message");
    }
   }`

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas? Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `GetMessage(..., WM_INPUT, WM_INPUT)`?

Comment: Technically you can but generally people do you want to do all their filtering in the WndProc function with a switch statement giving them more flexbility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved after much more research I found the winAPI walk through which I followed fixing the issue above by adding an:
`int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE unused, PSTR cmd, int show) {.....}` 
Function to register devices and create a window then call `GetMessage` which calls `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {....}` with the parameters occupied by the message ID,WParam and LParam corresponding the message event.
For anyone stuck with a similar issue follow this MSDN guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx